# Inkscape: I need help with arrangement of seven circles, their arrows and text

Tags: inkscape, svg

[image: My try]

This is my result.

I created the diagram for Wikipedia.

But I don't think the circles are symmetric and I don't know how to make them symmetric in Inkscape.

Same goes for the text.

I think that the arrows are fine on the circles, but I would like them to point exactly to the middle of the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create one circle and one arrow. Group them both
2. Enable snapping, snap other points, snap rotation centres
3. Click twice on the grouped arrow and circle
4. Click and drag so that the rotation centre snaps to the rotation centre of the circle
5. Ctrl+D (duplicate)
6. In the transform panel rotate 72°
7. Repeat steps 5 & 6 until finished

Example

[image]

For the text

1. Ungroup everything
2. Select both text and circle
3. Use the centre vertical and centre horizontal buttons in the Align and Distribute panel.

Repeat for other text and circles.

Example

[image]

Comment: thanks, I learned a lot! I will mention you on Wikipedia!

Comment: @FukaiMizumi There's no need. Advice is given freely here. Glad it helped.